# Error on adding a migration folder to my solution in "package manager" typing "enable-migration" visual studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework, migration

**PM> enable-migrations**

**I get an error(eManager) like this.**

1. I have two projects in my VS solution named as below :

   - eManager.Domain
   - eManager.Web

I added reference of eManager.Domain to eManager.Web even though its popping out the same error everytime.

error here :

```
More than one context type was found in the assembly 'eManager.Web'.
To enable migrations for eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb.
To enable migrations for eManager.Web.Models.UsersContext, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Models.UsersContext.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/23/perils-of-the-mvc4-accountcontroller.aspx) article and this [link](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/578)
The problem is easy to solve. As the error states, you can use the –ContextTypeName flag to specify your context class name. Note that you can only have migrations for one context in a project, so if you want to have migrations for both contexts you’ll need to move one to a different project. Again, my recommendation is to just remove the existing UsersContext the Internet project template creates, and take ownership of the user profile in your own context.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1968030/shahrooz-jefri ...thanks alot for the Answer

Answer (score 0):

In the Package Manager Console you have to change the Default Projetc Drop to your Web project 
and after exec enable-migrations for the context you want like that:

PM>  Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Web.Infraestruture.DepartmentDb

But remember you already have set the web as Startproject.